# are equivalence classes maximal with respect to the equivalence relation R?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I wanted to know if the following proof is right:

"If $[a]$ is an equivalence class for an equivalence relation $R$ on a set $U$, then there is no subset $Y$ of $U$ such that $[a]$ is properly included in Y and for all $x,y$ in $Y$, $xRy$."

If such subset $Y$ existed, there would be at least an element $t$ in $Y$ such that for all $z$ in $[a]$, $zRt$, and $t$ is not in $a$'s equivalence class.

But then,for the element $a$, we should have that $aRt$, in contradiction with the assumption that $[a]$ is a's equivalence class. There would be an element, namely $t$, that is in the relation $R$ with $a$ but is not included in $[a]$.

Is the proof correct?

Answer (score 1):

The proof is correct, although a bit complicated for something so trivial. You can shorten it to:

> Let $Y$ be such that $x \sim_R y \;\; \forall x,y \in Y$. For all $t \in Y$, we have $a \sim_R t$ which implies that $t \in [a]$. Thus, $Y \subseteq [a]$.